# "Pipe" command to new bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, puppet

I want to add my private key to the ssh-agent and I'm following [these](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-6.html) instructions. According to this the command

```
 ssh-agent bash
```

spawns a ssh-agent bash and I can add my key afterwards using ssh-add xxx. Is it possible to accomplish this in one line?  I'm using Puppet and can't think of another way to do this except running it in one exec command.

Comment: So this is rather a puppet problem than a bash or ssh-agent problem? It may be useful to adapt the title of the question. BTW: You do not need a new bash (except for puppet maybe which I am not familiar with). In general you can do this: `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`. This can be made a one-liner as: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s); ssh-add ..."`

Comment: The problem is that I'm pretty sure that I can't instruct puppet to execute the command in the newly spawned bash. Your command returns -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'. Without the ';' the command is still executed in the normal shell. (Without puppet, Ubuntu 12 shell)

Comment: But do you really need the new bash? Is it a problem that the commands are executed in the current shell?

Comment: You can use dopki module: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/devopera/dopki

Comment: No and Yes. Executing it in the current shell returns "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Comment: Strange. Does work here (in a normal shell without puppet).

Comment: Ok, I forgot to login with the correct user, it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you do not need a new bash as you can do this:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

This can be made a one-liner as:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s) ssh-add ..."
```

Comment: Specifically in Puppet I had to add "bash -c" at the beginning, because it wouldn't find eval.